# Android Studio enable off line mode not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 3.4. I enabled Off line mode- I want to work without internet. 
but it Still giving me errors like:

*No cached version listing for com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[10.2.4] available for offline mode.*
How I can fix this

I tried to Invalidate cache and restart while I am still one line. I synced my project with gradle.  I did every thing to make the project works fine while I am on line. After that I disabled my network and enabled Offline mode. still not working.
Any Idea how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

These errors are happening because Gradle can't use com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[10.2.4] in offline mode yet because it hasn't cached/pre-downloaded com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[10.2.4]. The solution is to disable offline mode, build, and then enable offline mode.